# Display XAML elements depending on selected item's type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, I have an Observable collection of abstract base class `Test`, which is actually full of its derivative classes `SqlTest` and `ConfigTest`.

I have a combo box which allows the user to select an item from the observable collection and am wanting different controls depending on the type of test chosen.

I have tried using DataTemplates but haven't managed to get them working for anything other than lists.

**Test.cs**

```
public abstract class Test
{
    public string Number { get; set; } // A string as test numbers can contain multiple decimal points depending on the section

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Condition { get; set; }

    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Test>();

    public Test SelectedTest
    {
        get { return _selectedTest; }
        set
        {
            _selectedTest = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTest");
        }
    }

    private Test _selectedTest;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Tests.Add(new SqlTest("Change Me", "Check Me", "2", "A Test", "Condition", "Result"));
        Tests.Add(new ConfigTest("key", "value", "orig", "1.10", "Test2", "this is a result", "or is it?"));
        Tests.Add(new SqlTest("Change Me", "Check Me", "2", "A Test", "Condition", "Result"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**My xaml**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock><Run Text="{Binding Number}" /><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="-" /><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="{Binding Description}" /></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

<!-- The Conditions of the test -->
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Text="{Binding SelectedTest.Condition}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

<!-- The Result of the test -->
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" Text="{Binding SelectedTest.Result}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: That's exactly what they are for.

Comment: I can't get them to work for anything other than list items. I've been trying to get them working for other things all day.

Comment: You should show the XAML and any relevant code that you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple example I whipped up in a few minutes for you.

`MainWindowVm` is the View Model for the main window. It has 2 properties, the first is a list of `Thing`s, the second is the selected `Thing`.  The main window binds a combobox to `Things` with `SelectedThing` as the `SelectedItem`.  There is a `ContentControl` bound to `SelctedThing` also, with 2 `DataTemplates` defined in its resources.  The `DataType` property of the template is automatically used by the `ContentControl` and compared against the type of its content when `SelectedThing` changes.  Whatever markup is inside the template is displayed below the combobox.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Things}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedThing}" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Path=SelectedThing}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Thing1}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="This Is the template for Thing1" />
                        <Button Content="This is a button!" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Thing2}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="This Is the template for Thing2" />
                        <TextBox Text="Enter some text" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowVm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class MainWindowVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainWindowVm()
        {
            Things = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            Things.Add(new Thing1());
            Things.Add(new Thing2());
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Object> Things { get; set; }

        private Object _selectedThing;
        public Object SelectedThing
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedThing;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedThing)
                {
                    _selectedThing = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedThing)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Thing1` and `Thing2` are just empty classes.

Comment: Thanks,  I think my problem was that I wasn't using Path in my bindings (although it could've been anything).

Comment: The `Path` keyword isn't actually required, `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing}"` should work just as well, but I like to use it for clarity.

Comment: I really don't know then. I've tried that many things that I'm just grateful for your help.

Comment: The key to the whole thing is the `ContentControl` and the `DataTemplates` as Resources.  Because the Templates don't have Ids the `ContentControl` will use whichever one has a matching `DataType` as it's "default" template.